# How to ignore files or directories in nose2?

Tags: python, nose2

I have a nose.cfg file which i'm porting to nose2. I can't see any way in [the nose2 docs](https://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to ignore a file or directory.

In nose 1 this was done via these two flags:

```
ignore-files=settings_test*
exclude-dir=ignorethisdir
```

How can this be done in nose2?

Comment: well, not an answer to your question, but did you ever consider using py.test? It's very nice...

Comment: >2y later, we are now using py.test with great enthusiasm :)

Answer (score 4):

The **exclude-dir** is available when you install nose-exclude. This plugin is currently only available for nose1: https://bitbucket.org/kgrandis/nose-exclude/overview

What is available is defining:

`__test__ = False`

in each TestCase or TestSuite inherited class.

They *must* be inherited from these classes for this to work. This is made available by the dundertest plugin which comes with nose2 and is enabled by default.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work when nose2 is running under python 2 and you're trying to get it to skip a python 3 source file that it can't even parse to get that far...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently noting yet to ignore directories as of June 2019.

Another approach would be to specify the directories you are actually using by specifying `--start-dir` option multiple times or having it in `nose2.cfg` file.

See the [documentation](https://nose2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-to-run).

Comment: specifying --start-dir option multiple times  doesn't work: "No data was collected."